# How to insert indent in markdown

Tags: markdown, indentation, blogs

I want to make the format of my text just as below by using markdown:

[image: wanted format]

**how could i write the markdown file?**

Comment: Markdown is intended to produce HTML, not a specific presentation. Therefore it would be helpful to know what is the desired outcome in terms of HTML.

Comment: Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6046263/1959808

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 1. 1
 1. 2
   1. 1
   1. 2
 1. 3
```

outputs

1. 1
2. 2

   1. 1
   2. 2
3. 3

the sub-numbers `2.1.` is not super easy to achieve in HTML, that's the limitation here.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that this solution works just by accident. The proper way would be to do it in CSS with the `counter` function.
http://www.standardista.com/css3/creating-counters-with-generated-content/

Comment: @Jonas linkrot: https://web.archive.org/web/20221103084209/https://www.standardista.com/css3/creating-counters-with-generated-content/ though 2012 one is a bit more expressive: https://web.archive.org/web/2012/https://www.standardista.com/css3/creating-counters-with-generated-content/

Answer (score 4):

As a general answer to the title of the question:

Use the "Greater-Than Sign followed by a Space **(> )**" will indent the line:

```
> This line will be indented.
```

This will work in not only Jupyter but also other markdowns.

E.g. The indented text shown here on the StackOverflow page is like this:

> This line will be indented.

Credit from this [IBM markdown cheatsheet](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHGWL_1.2.3/analyze-data/markd-jupyter.html).

Comment: This gives a blockquote. It's intended for quoting, not indenting.