# Is there a way to create a user defined function in Markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

Created a blog using Jekyll and git hub pages. I need to indent to align a list of expenses. I found a way how, but I would like to insert that into a function.

Example:

1. Sum of Contractor expenses - $6,800
2. Heating and Air - $5,100
3. Fridge and Stove - $1,100
4. Hardware store purchases - $5,000
5. Miscellaneous - $2,000

I would like all of the amounts to line up.

According to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046263/how-to-indent-a-few-lines-in-markdown-markup), I can use `&nbsp;` to create a space. However, I need to insert a lot of these to obtain what I want.

Another suggestion is `Tab+Space` but this doesn't seem to work in the middle of the text.

From the same post, I tried using `Alt+0+1+6+0` and that seems to work.

The expected results would look like this.

1. Sum of Contractor expenses - `TAB;`$6,800
2. Heating and Air - `TAB;(5)`$5,100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the answer to that SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046263/how-to-indent-a-few-lines-in-markdown-markup) states:

> There's no way to do that in markdown's native features. However markdown allows inline HTML...

There are a couple of ways you could do this. You could use a `<table>` element, where the HTML looks like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Sum of Contractor expenses</td><td>$6,800</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Heating and Air</td><td>$5,100</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Fridge and Stove</td><td>$1,100</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Hardware store purchases</td><td>$5,000</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Miscellaneous</td><td>$2,000</td></tr>
</table>
```

Or, you could use class names and CSS, where the HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
  <span class="description">Sum of Contractor expenses</span>
  <span class="cost">$6,800</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="description">Heating and Air</span>
  <span class="cost">$5,100</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="description">Fridge and Stove</span>
  <span class="cost">$1,100</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="description">Hardware store purchases</span>
  <span class="cost">$5,000</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="description">Miscellaneous</span>
  <span class="cost">$2,000</span>
</div>
```

And, the CSS looks like this:

```
.description { width: 100px }
.cost { width: 30px; text-align: right; }
```

Note 1: You'll need to play with the widths to get things aligned the way you want.

Note 2: You could also apply class names and CSS to the `<td>` tags in the `<table>`.

Comment: Of you could just use Kramdown's native [table](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables) syntax.

Comment: Using table method was straightforward.