# How do I indent content in markdown?

Tags: markdown, indentation

I'm trying to make my paragraphs, images and tables indented (hanging) in markdown but when I try to just Tab the (control signals for each instruction), it turns into a box for some reason.

I would like my readme file to look something like this:

1. Title:

   description...

```
11. **Main Control Unit**

    We have used filled ROM with values of every opcodes' signals as a decoder to generate all possible signals to control each instruction from its opcode in this datapath. In our design we chose to a ROM that works as a decoder and connected to a splitter that group signals in their specified place as shown in the table below:

    | Bits | Singal/Signals |
    | --- | --- |
    | 0-1 | WBdata |
    | 2 | MemWr |
    | 3 | MemRd |
    | 4 | AluSrc |
    | 5 | ExtOp |
    | 6 | RegWr |
    | 7-8 | RegDst |

    The Control Unit's purpose is to produce the signals to the Register file, ALU, and Data Memory. There is a single input for the 5-bit opcode, and 7 signal outputs. The outputs are as following:

    - WBdata (bit 0&1): Selects whether the data on BusW should be coming from the ALU or the Data memory.
    - MemWr (bit 2): for store instructions.
    - MemRd (bit 3): for load instructions.
    - AluSrc (bit 4): Selects whether the 2nd ALU input should be from BusB or the extended 5-bit immediate.
    - ExtOp (bit 5): Controls the extension of the 5-bit immediate
    - RegWr (bit 6): Enables the writing of the registers in the register file.
    - RegDst (bit 7 & 8): Chooses which register should be the register destination.

    ![](./img/Picture17.png)

    ![](./img/Picture18.png)

**Control signals for each instruction**

| Instruction | Op | RegDst | RegWr | ExtOp | AluSrc | MemRd | MemWr | WBdata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **R-type** | 0, 1 | 01 | 1 | x | 0 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **ANDI** | 4 | 00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **CANDI** | 5 | 00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **ORI** | 6 | 00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **XORI** | 7 | 00 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **ADDI** | 8 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **NADDI** | 9 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **SEQI** | 10 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **SLTI** | 11 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **SLL**| 12 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **SRL** | 13 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **SRA** | 14 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **ROR** | 15 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 00 |
| **BEQ** | 16 | xx | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | xx |
| **BNE** | 17 | xx | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | xx |
| **BLT** | 18 | xx | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | xx |
| **BGT** | 19 | xx | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | xx |
| **LW** | 20 | 00 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 01 |
| **SW** | 21 | 00 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | xx |
| **JALR** | 27 | 00 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| **J** | 28 | xx | 0 | x | x | 0 | 0 | xx |
| **JAL** | 29 | 10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 |
| **IMM** | 30 | xx | x | x | x | x | x | xx |
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to indent a few lines in Markdown markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046263/how-to-indent-a-few-lines-in-markdown-markup)